# If $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\mathcal{T}=\{X,\emptyset,\{a\}, \{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$ find all $\mathcal{T}$-neighborhoods of a

Tags: general-topology

If $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\mathcal{T}=\{X,\emptyset,\{a\}, \{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$ find all $\mathcal{T}$-neighborhoods of $a$.

I know by definition if $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space with $x\in X$, a $\mathcal{T}$-neighborhood of $x$ is a subset $N$ of $X$ for which there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U \subseteq N$

So a $\mathcal{T}$-neighborhood of $a$ would be $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,c\}$ I think.

I'm not really sure how to approach this and get a little confused when given sets like this.

Answer (score 3):

There are three open sets containig $a$: $X, \{a\}, \{a,b,c\}$.
This means by your definition all supersets of any of these sets are nbhds, which, since $\{a\}$ is already open, boils down to $\{a\} .\cup P(\{b,c,d\})$ (element-wise union).
$$N(a) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{a,d\}, \{a,b,c\}, \{a,b,d\}, \{a,c,d\}, X\}$$

Another notion of a nbhd forces it to be open as well, though, which would only allow for $\{a\}, \{a,b,c\}$ and $X$ to qualify as nbhds.

Comment: @OP Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your definition these two examples are correct as they are subsets of $X$ contained in an open subset $X$. Then you also have $\{a\}$ and $X$ for example because they are contained in open subsets since $X$ is an open subset.